# button position issue using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below two lines of code. show1 and show2 are buttons on my JSP Page that position according to below code. However, button show2 is displayed little lower that button show1. How to resolve this issue.

```
  document.getElementById('show1').style.marginTop="33%";

  document.getElementById('show2').style.marginTop="33%";
```

Comment: Can you show us the HTML (and CSS)? If you set up a jsFiddle, you'd most likely get a good answer

Comment: There can be lot of other styles that could be the cause to the button alignment. It is not possible to answer without seeing code relavent css & html. Or try to simulate the issue in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Are you sure that the container of `show1` and `show2` are the same size? If you change the values to something impirical (eg `30px`) are they still not aligned?

Comment: Well, it does not seems to be any wrong if this is how you code looks like... http://jsfiddle.net/yvXZX/ Does someone see any jQuery related code? :/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using `position: absolute;` for each of them.

```
document.getElementById('show1').style.position = 'absolute';
document.getElementById('show2').style.position = 'absolute';
```